# Flutter: How to retrieve all the Firebase user data from its uid?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks something like this:
[image]
Now as I start adding more and more data I will be getting variety of users. I want to extract data from one user based on their user ID. I tried using these codes but none of them worked. I am getting data in bulk of all the users but I just want one of them. Here's my attempt:

```
final data=await _collection.collection('UserDetails').getDocuments();
    //print(user.uid);
    DocumentReference ref = await _collection.collection('UserDetails').document(user.uid);
    var lister=await ref.collection('Name');
    print(lister);
```

This is the code for getting all their data:

```
for(var msgs in data.documents)
      {
        print(msgs.data);
      }
```

I want a function or anything which could return data in this way:
function.giveUserID('uid').giveDataYouwanttoExtract('Attribute')
I can filter out using string conditions from all the data I am getting but as the database rises it will have to extract tons of data at once which will affect the performance and so I want to do this in this way. Please let me know if there's any way to just extract data of one user based on their uid or email or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use queries. The code below returns all the users where name is equals to the Jack.

```
await _db.collection("UserDetails")
      .where("Name", isEqualTo: "Jack")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
            snapshot.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot){
                print(documentSnapshot.data);
            });
       });
```